# Listening for a window.postMessage within nested iframes

Tags: reactjs, iframe, window, postmessage

I own an application, we can call 'B' whose domain is b.com. My application runs as an `iframe` inside an application that I do not own, we can call 'A' whose domain is a.com.

My application (B) renders an `iframe` of another service, we can call this application 'C' whose domain is c.com.

So, overall we have nested iframes:
A -> B (my domain as an iframe) -> C (iframe).

What I need to do is have B listen for a `window.postMessage` event that is emitted by C.

I only have access to B's codebase.

This code is not working as expected:

```
const logMessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
  console.log(event)
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('message', logMessage)

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('message', logMessage)
  }
}, [])
```